# How to change the color of Anychart dot map.?

Tags: javascript, css, anychart

Is there a way to change the map color in Anycharts dot maps? I want the continents to be blue instead of plain white.

I tried `.color()`, `.fill` etc from the documentation but can't get it to work.

[Anycharts dot maps sample](https://www.anychart.com/products/anymap/gallery/Maps_Point_Maps_(Dot_Maps)/Airplane_Crashes_since_1970_till_2009.php)

Comment: You should show what you tried as a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
map.unboundRegions()
   .enabled(true)
   .fill('#E1E1E1')
   .stroke('#D2D2D2');
```

Change the fill color `#E1E1E1` to whatever color you want. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Carlos is right, this is exactly how you should change the map color.
Please check the sample: https://playground.anychart.com/hukHcUUi (#E1E1E1 color is replaced with #aa99cc here)